# LINQPad calling dispose on my typed data context

Tags: c#, .net, linqpad

I'm using LINQPad with a typed data context from my own assembly. The context class wraps up a connection object for my database, which gets opened in the context constructor and closed in its Dispose method (the context class implements `IDisposable`).

The issue I'm encountering is that LINQPad creates a new instance of the context class when a query is run, but doesn't call dispose on any existing instances until the window is closed. Therefore if I run a query a second time without closing the window, the query hangs as the context is attempting to open a connection that is already open by another instance.

How can I get LINQPad to call Dispose on my context class after every query? I guess one option is just to call `this.Dispose()` at the end of every query entered into LINQPad, but it's a bit of a pain to have to do this.  Is there any way to automate this?

As an aside, I notice there's a LINQPad setting named "Always use Fresh Application Domains" in Edit->Preferences->Advanced tab, which when set to true, no longer causes the queries run in a single window to hang. But unfortunately it still hangs if I run a query in another LINQPad window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, which has now been fixed (from version 5.04).

However, bear in mind that LINQPad will not dispose the data context until you re-run the query (or close it). This is so that when you click hyperlinks that run additional queries, the context is still alive.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use it like this?

```
void Main(){

    using(var context = new YourAssembly.ContextClass()){
        //Your Query

    }

}
```